# Translate recursive JS function into Obj-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, recursion, objective-c-blocks

A friend of mine helped me work through a computation problem where I am trying to create a series based on some conditions. He used JS with recursion. I sat down to translate this into Obj-C and am stumped.

I have the starting point below. The idea was to use a recursive block, is that the right approach? Blocks and recursion are really hard for me to get my head around. Is the skeleton below on the right track?

JS Version

```
function series(F, S, Y, N = 0, result = []) {
  var entry

  if (N < 2) {
    entry = N * (F + S * (N - 1))
  } else {
    entry = (F + S * (N - 1))
  }

  if (entry > Y) {
    return result
  }

  result.push(entry)

  return series(F, S, Y, N + 1, result)
}

// series (90, 30, 200)
// (5) [0, 90, 120, 150, 180]
```

Starting of Attempt at Obj-C Version -- sorry this is ugly

```
-(NSArray*) seriesWithF:(int)_F S:(int)_S Y:(int)_Y {

int F = _F;
int S = _S;
int Y = _Y;
int N = 0;
NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray init];

    __block void ( ^series)(int, int, int, int, NSMutableArray*) = ^ void (int F, int S, int Y, int N, NSMutableArray* result) 
    {

    // logic
    int entry = [result of logic]
    [result addObject:[NSNumber initWithInt:entry]];

     series(F, S, Y, N, result);

    }

 series(F, S, Y, N, result);
 return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the block. A much more direct translation works:

```
- (NSArray *)series:(int)f s:(int)s y:(int)y n:(int)n result:(NSArray *)result {
    int entry;
    if (n < 2) {
        entry = n * (f + s * (n - 1));
    } else {
        entry = (f + s * (n - 1));
    }

    if (entry > y) {
        return result;
    }

    NSMutableArray *newResult = [result mutableCopy];
    [newResult addObject:@(entry)];

    return [self series:f s:s y:y n:n+1 result:newResult];
}

- (void)someOtherMethod {
    NSArray *result = [self series:90 s:30 y:200 n:0 result:@[]];
    NSLog(@"Result = %@", result);
}
```

Comment: BTW: I do not see any need for a method. Either one should make it a function or a method of – likely – `NSArray` and omit the last parameter. At least it should be a class method. (And if you put together class method and method of `NSArray` it looks like a convenience allocator.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have used a block to address the lack of default parameter values (for `N` and `result`), there is nothing wrong with your code outline *per se* but a simpler approach is to use a local (`static`) C function to do the job. To do this simply translate the JS into the equivalent C and then use your Objective-C method to call this C function passing in the values for `N` and `result`.

However in this particular case your friends solution is more complicated than it need be, a much simpler algorithm will produce your series.

Consider the first condition, `N < 2`, which given `N` starts at zero will be true for just `0` & `1`. In the first case `entry` will be set to `0` and in the second to the same value as it would be in the `else` branch... A complex way to set the first value in your sequence to zero.

Next consider the recursion; there is nothing complex involved in the call, just one parameter is incremented. Incrementing a value is easily done with iteration.

Finally each recursive call calculates the next value "from scratch", but that next value is just the previous one with `S` added to it. Again iteration is suited to this.

Based on these observations let's simplify:

```
- (NSArray *) seriesWithF:(int)F S:(int)S Y:(int)Y
{
   NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray new];
   [result addObject:@(0)];        // you always start with zero

   int entry = F;                  // next value is F
   while (entry <= Y)              // iterate as long as in range
   {
      [result addObject:@(entry)]; // add to sequence
      entry += S;                  // increment
   }

   return result;
}
```

HTH